# Nested aggregate functions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, nested, aggregate-functions

How to do this in Rails?:

```
select avg(cnt)
from
(
    select
        count(*) as cnt
    from
        sngs s
        inner join clbs c on c.id = s.clb_id
    where
        c.user_id = 35
    group by
        date(s.record_date)
) sc
```

The line

current_user.sngs.joins(:clb).average("count(*)", group: "date(record_date)")

gives an error:

**PG::Error: ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested LINE 1: SELECT AVG(count(*)) .............**

Answer (score 1):

I **didn't test** it, but maybe it looks like this:

```
Sng.joins(:clbs).where("clbs.user_id = 35").group(:record_date).average
```

You should take a look at `ActiveRecord` query interface on the Rails Guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
This link explains many of the methods you should use to query like this.

**EDIT**

Take a look at `count`, `average`, `having`, `group` and chaning all of them together.

Comment: "Undefined method 'group' for 1420:Fixnum" because count is a fixnum.

Comment: This is just an idea. If you look at the guides they would teach you to combine all of this methods on the right way.

Comment: I decided to use direct SQL query.